# Drools expert + Spring MVC

Tags: java, dependencies, drools

I'm new to `Drools` I tried to implement the sample hello world of the drools into my project and It seems to be working quite well, but I'm really bothered by the `Drools` dependency because I really don't know what is the use of it. Just wondering if I need to set the `Drools` dependency? I will appreciate to hear it from you guys.

Comment: How are your dependencies set at the moment? Please add your ivy/maven etc configs.

Comment: How to know what dependency I'm using? Sorry for a noob question. I'm only have `web.xml` and for the `defaultController.xml` configuration, and there is no dependency tag in the xml. So which one is it?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question earlier. If you want to have Drools rules as part of you app, you'll to include Drools libs in your app.

Comment: I did add the library, I thought you were talking about POM that I didn't have

Comment: One more thing, there's a Spring-Drools project, which should include pretty all you need, and in addition will will bring Spring DI.

Comment: I'm using Spring MVC, so the all lib for MVC will be provided?

Comment: Spring MVC provides libs needed for MVC development. If you want Drools, you'll have to include Spring-Dools.

Comment: You don't need Spring-Drools to use Drools in a Spring application. You just need the Drools dependencies. I really don't understand the question though. If you want to use Drools then of course you need to include Drools dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we need to set Drools Dependencies.

Drools is broken down into a few modules, some are required during rule development/compiling, and some are required at runtime.

In most scenarios, programmers will simply want to include all the dependencies at runtime, and this is fine. It allows you to have the most flexibility.

The following is a description of the important libraries that make up JBoss Drools:

knowledge-api.jar - this provides the interfaces and factories. It also helps clearly show what is intended as a user api and what is just an engine api.

knowledge-internal-api.jar - this provides internal interfaces and factories.

drools-core.jar - this is the core engine, runtime component. Contains both the RETE engine and the LEAPS engine. This is the only runtime dependency if you are pre-compiling rules (and deploying via Package or RuleBase objects).

drools-compiler.jar - this contains the compiler/builder components to take rule source, and build executable rule bases. This is often a runtime dependency of your application, but it need not be if you are pre-compiling your rules. This depends on drools-core.

drools-jsr94.jar - this is the JSR-94 compliant implementation, this is essentially a layer over the drools-compiler component. Note that due to the nature of the JSR-94 specification, not all features are easily exposed via this interface. In some cases, it will be easier to go direct to the Drools API, but in some environments the JSR-94 is mandated.

drools-decisiontables.jar - this is the decision tables 'compiler' component, which uses the drools-compiler component. This supports both excel and CSV input formats.

Reference:
https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR5/droolsjbpm-introduction-docs/html_single/#d0e58